# There is a scary and loud server on my table! -How do I talk to it?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

There is a giant and absurdly loud server lying on my table. It is connected to a powersupply and to a LAN and I am helplessly standing next to it.
The server is new that is it does not have an OS installed.

**How do I communicate with it?** (I know to basics of SHH but I have no idea how to establish such a connection with a new device)

**What would be a good way to install ubuntu on it?** (It has a CD-drive)

Comment: How about reading the manual?

Comment: Take a look at the user's profile, which states 'delete me' in the description.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some kind of automated provisioning on your network, then it's just a normal computer.

As you would with a new desktop, connect a keyboard and monitor to it, then make an OS install disk of the type you want (for Ubuntu, download the server install ISO and burn it to a CD), shove it in the drive, and install it.

Comment: Some more informations : once you start it with a screen connected to it, you should be able to hit a key like F1 (or other, it should be wrote at login screen, if just a log company is displayed, press escap to see more infos) to access to the bios. There you can select how to install an OS (network, Usb, CD rom, for example)